# Is it possible to catch ActiveModel::Errors with Raven?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sentry

I am integrating Raven in my rails project.

Is it possible to capture `ActiveModel::Errors` with `Raven.capture_exception`?

I mean, when you call `object.save` or `object.valid?` the errors get stored in `object.errors` so is it possible to do `Raven.capture_exception(object.errors)`?

Comment: do you mean validation errors, etc?

Comment: Your question in unclear to me. When you call a method that would raise an exception when the validation fails – like `save!` or `create!` then the exception would be recorded via Raven. When you just call `save` or `valid?` which doesn't raise an exception then you want to do what?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev Yes

Comment: @spickermann when you call `object.save` or `object.valid?` the errors get stored in `object.errors` so is it possible to do `Raven.capture_excception(object.errors)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```rb
unless model_instance.valid?
  Raven.capture_exception(model_instance.errors)
end
```

i.e. check if my `model_instance` object does have errors (invalid) so I send them to Sentry

29.04 UPD

What about this code? I haven't tried, but I would be glad if it works

```rb
unless model_instance.valid?
  model_instance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    Raven.capture_exception(ActiveModel::ValidationError, { message: msg })
  end
end
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often a very helpful addition

Comment: Not possible since `Raven.capture_exception` calls `message` method on the first arguement and `model_instance.errors` doesn't have a `message` method.

Comment: I guess you mixed up `capture_exception` with `capture_message` methods. I updated code a bit

Comment: Second one may work if we pass an instance of `ActiveModel::ValidationError`. But I have tried with the first one it didn't worked and got `undefined method message` error.